# what is the proper way of handling the errors when working with threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In my project for some reason I am creating my thread in suspended state and after some state I am resuming the thread. So when resuming the thread sometime it might work or sometime it is not. So what is the proper way of handling the error if doesn't work?? Should I retry for resuming the thread or should I wait for some time or any possible appropriate handling mechanism?? Please guide me the best way of handling the scenarios. I am using ACE thread library here.

Comment: Why doesn't the thread work? With what error does it return?

Comment: It doesn't work sometime. It returns the status 0.

Comment: `It doesn't work` is not enough. Maybe you can provide the code it should execute. Maybe you can try returning different error codes to show the progress in the thread. How are you starting your thread?

Comment: Specifically, you need to specify what "It doesn't work" means, does the thread not start, or does the thread run but fails to do something (such as open a file that doesn't exist), or does the thread cause an exception (either C++ or a hardware exception)? These are very different things.

Comment: Suspending and resuming threads is dangerous, a thread should block when it has nothing to do (by taking a semaphore for example), and should be unblocked with some kind of notification like another thread giving the semaphore.

Comment: sorry...when I am trying to resume the thread, it doesn't start.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a [message queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue)?  A simple implementation would just be an [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) of updates, where each value in the vector represents an update like loading an asset (whose update architecture would include success/error code and filename) or letting another thread know that a key has been pressed/released.

EDIT:

As Damon said, you also need a [mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34558/3151642) so only one thread at a time is editing the message queue.

Comment: Message queue is generally a good suggestion with "thread" in mind, even if the actual problem that the OP is having isn't yet known. But you should add "and a mutex" to your suggestion of using "just" a `std::vector` (I would personally rather use a ringbuffer, too - `vector` isn't really great for that purpose).

Comment: @Damon Yes, totally forgot about a [mutex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34558/3151642)...