# Why is IBAction throwing exception?

Tags: ios, swift, sigabrt

```
import UIKit

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func btnActionLogin(_ sender: Any?) {
        print("Why is this error?")
    }
}
```

After connecting the button to my view controller, when I tap the button, the app keeps crashing with an Error: (Thread 1: signal SIGABRT)

Why?  I am just connecting the button from the storyboard to the code like normal..

Comment: can you attach complete crash or screenShot ?

Comment: Did you link your custom viewcontroller to the view in Interface Builder?

Comment: @CasWolters  I am not quite sure what do you mean coz I have set it to be the initial View Controller in the Storyboard.  If I didnt get you wrong,  I have added the the Class name to the controller in the storyboard Custom Class as LoginViewController

Comment: Show us the crash log, it has often (if not almost all the times) the correct hints about the error.

Comment: @Larme  I have found these..
Unknown class LoginViewController in Interface Builder file
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fccc4405e50
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController btnActionLogin:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fccc4405e50'

Comment: @Larme But I am confused with this log because I have already linked the class to the controller :(

Comment: From it: You didn't set correctly the class of the UIViewController to `LoginViewController` (your custom one) in the Storyboard

Comment: Also make sure that no any other IBAction connected with that button action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the Module part is not None and set to your target name in addition to class set to Your custom class name

[image]

Comment: this is the problem.  I have sorted it now.  Thanks.  But it is just strange coz it has always been there.  All I have done is click on it and press enter again :/

Comment: yes clicking enter on class name  re assigns the module

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this link : [Swift error : signal SIGABRT how to solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546497/swift-error-signal-sigabrt-how-to-solve-it)

and follow second answer. Suspecting you have connected another action or so and might have deleted it by mistake.[image: Attached a picture, replicating your scenraio, Please look at it]