# signal SIGABRT on instantiateViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, sigabrt

I have create a second view controller with a storyboard. I have specified a StoryBoard ID. I have created a class for this controller and specified this class in the story board as well:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    // It is really empty
}
```

Then I am trying to activate this controller doing quite a standard operation:

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

let secondViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController

self.present(secondViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

However, when execution reaches and invokes `storyBoard.instantiateViewController` - I get `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT` without any description (clicking on it gives nothing):

[image]

I have already looked at this QA: [Swift error : signal SIGABRT how to solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546497/swift-error-signal-sigabrt-how-to-solve-it) - clean & build doesn't solve the problem.

I guess I am missing something in the configuration of my second view controller. But I can not find what exactly. Any advices?

Comment: Keep clicking the "play" button in the debugger until you get a full error and stack trace in the debugger console (maybe 3 or 4 clicks should do it).

Comment: @maddy if I click "Play" button it asks me `Stop "<Name of my app>"?`

Comment: And clicking "Continue" in debugger gives me `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` without a stacktrace

Comment: Most likely your forced-cast is failing. Check the class in the storyboard.

Comment: you checked the checkbox of use storyboard id ?

Comment: @sanjaykmwt which checkbox particularly?

Comment: when you give storyboardID to a viewController through storyboard there is a small checkBox behind that

Comment: @sanjaykmwt I will check this evening and reply

Comment: @sanjaykmwt I am not sure which checkbox you are actually talking about. There is a checkbox "Use Storyboard ID" related to the "Restoration ID" property. So this is unrelated to the problem. However I have tried to check it as well, but it doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify your storyboard filename and use it in the line:

```
let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
```

Comment: Thanks bro! You've saved my day. That was an issue. I used improper name of the StoryBoard. It should be the same as a name of my storyboard file to which I am going to switch