# Unity iOS Generated project fails to load framework : dylib, reason image not found

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, build, frameworks

I currently have an issue with an XCode project, targeting iOS, generated by Unity : a framework imported from Unity is not loaded at runtime.

I use Unity 2018.1.4f1, XCode 9.4.1, the framework is a SDK in progress (stable version).

The generated XCode project builds fine, but when the app launches, I get the following error :

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @rpath/MyFramework.framework/MySDK   Referenced from:
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/55523B8-4DE8-432Y-BDAB-C9A4B09IK1DE/MyApp.app/MyApp
>   Reason: image not found

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24333981/ios-app-with-framework-crashed-on-device-dyld-library-not-loaded-xcode-6-beta) was handy, and lead me to try the following :

- add my .framework to "embedded binaries"
- add my .framework to a "Copy File" build phase, targeting "Framework" directory
- checked the slices of my .framework (armv7, arm64)
- close XCode > delete .framework > delete derived data > clean build folder > restart macos > reimport .framework
- Runpath

None of the above solved my issue, and I have no ideas / forums left to try.

Have you ever met this situation ? Any Idea to work on ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: are you opening the xcode project file instead of the xcode workspace file by any chance?

Comment: Unity only generates a .xcodeproj : https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StructureOfXcodeProject.html. I have also checked the targets. I wonder if the issue does not come from the .framework itself

Comment: the log also gives me a SIGABRT error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546497/swift-error-signal-sigabrt-how-to-solve-it. Could be an outlet issue.