# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT, no incomplete outlets AFAIK

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and am getting a *Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error*.

**Expected:**
I'm using swiping navigation for elements on the main view controller page: left (Reflection), right (Goals), and up (Insights).

**Actual:**
Left and right work as expected; however, up triggers the SIGABRT error.

I've read this StackOverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43546497/swift-error-signal-sigabrt-how-to-solve-it), and I don't seem to have any incomplete outlets, but I'm also not clear if each triggered segue needs an accompanying presenting segue or if so, how to add that correctly:

[image: Connection Inspector View]

Below is the **main** view controller called "ViewController2"

> //MAIN

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let leftSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeAction(swipe:)))
        leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(leftSwipe)

        let rightSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeAction(swipe:)))
        rightSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(rightSwipe)

        let upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeAction(swipe:)))
        upSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(upSwipe)


    }
```

Here is the **up** view controller called "ViewController3"

> //INSIGHTS

```
class ViewController3: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let upSwipe = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeAction(swipe:)))
        upSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.up
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(upSwipe)

    }
```

- Insights has the appropriate ViewController3 class
- Main points to ViewController2 class
- The storyboard segue identifier from Main to Insights is named "goUp"

Thanks for your advice and help!

Comment: Could you give the error message in console when this happens?

Comment: @cristik Thank you! Smart clarification. 

Fix:
I removed the extra Case 4 parameter (swipeDown) since I hadn't used it for that main view controller. 


2018-08-01 23:03:09.779549-0700 Kintsugi Mindful Wellness[63589:12403287] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<Kintsugi_Mindful_Wellness.ViewController2: 0x7fb00151eaf0>) has no segue with identifier 'goDown''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix: I removed the extra Case 4 parameter (swipeDown) since I hadn't used it for that main view controller.

2018-08-01 23:03:09.779549-0700 Kintsugi Mindful Wellness[63589:12403287] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'goDown''