# Running website on app in xcode and getting error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Tags: html, ios, swift, xcode

I'm setting up an app with my website and I was getting no errors until i run the app and get the next one: "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT".

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { 

// this is where i am getting the error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"


var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
```

//error i get when running is *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException', reason: 'Could not instantiate class named WKWebView because no class named WKWebView was found; the class needs to be defined in source code or linked in from a library (ensure the class is part of the correct target)'

Comment: Check this: [Swift error : signal SIGABRT how to solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48072511/7430022)

Comment: In which view controller you use the webview? Show code of that view controller

Answer (score 0):

Open **Project > Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries**

Click on **+** icon and add `WebKit.framework`.

Clean Project and Run will fix your issue.