# How to get rid of OpenCv's Bad argument error

Tags: c++, opencv, error-handling, video-capture

I have three periodic real-time tasks that execute simultaneously, each on a different processor(core) for video capturing using OpenCV.

In order to synchronize between the three tasks, I used an array of `cv::Mat` and each time I swap the index in order to avoid a data race. Thanks to the answers to [my previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548742/opencv-writing-and-reading-from-a-buffer) on buffer reading/writing synchronization, I come up with this solution :

```
cv::Mat frame[3];
int frame_index_write = 0;
int frame_index_read = 1;
int frame_index_read_ = 2;

int SwapIndex(int *fi){
return *fi = (*fi + 1) % 3;
}
```

Now, the first task grabs a capture and stores it in a buffer and broadcast a signal to the other tasks, so they can get the captured frames :

```
 while (1)
{
    capture.grab();
    capture.retrieve(frame[frame_index_write], CHANNEL);
    SwapIndex(&frame_index_write);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&synch_condition); /* After capturing the frame
                                                signal the displaying tasks*/
   }
```

The second task gets the captured frame and displays it:

```
 while (1)
{
    pthread_cond_wait(&synch_condition, &frame_rw); /*wait for the capturing
                                                      func to send a signal*/
    if (frame[frame_index_read].data)
    {
        cv::imshow(CAPTURED_IMAGE_WINDOW_NAME, frame[frame_index_read]);
        SwapIndex(&frame_index_read);
        cv::waitKey(1);
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Frame reading error" << std::endl;
    }
    }
```

The third task gets the captured frame and applies an edge detection process before displaying it :

```
while (1)
{
    pthread_cond_wait(&synch_condition, &frame_rw); /*wait for the capturing
                                                      func to send a signal*/
    if (frame[frame_index_read_].data)
    {
        cv::cvtColor(frame[frame_index_read_], gray_capture, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        cv::blur(gray_capture, detected_edges, cv::Size(3, 3));
        cv::Canny(detected_edges, detected_edges, 0, 100, 3);
        cv::imshow(EDGE_IMAGE_WINDOW_NAME, detected_edges);
        SwapIndex(&frame_index_read_);
        cv::waitKey(1);
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Frame reading error" << std::endl;
    }
    }
```

My code seems to work perfectly and the results were also as expected but when I stop the execution on the terminal I got the following output indicating an error :

> VIDIOC_DQBUF: Invalid argument
>
> OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unknown array type) in cvarrToMat, file /build/opencv-L2vuMj/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 943
>        terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
>        what():  /build/opencv-L2vuMj/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:943: error: (-5) Unknown array type in function cvarrToMat

Is there a way to handle this kind of error?

The complete code is hosted at [Github](https://github.com/sendjasni/ReVC_opencv/blob/master/re_task.cpp)

Any help would be so greatly appreciated on this topic.

Comment: You should stop the consumer threads as well when you "stop the execution on the terminal"

Comment: @Botje What do you mean by that? I thought by terminating the program, the created threads are automatically terminated.

Comment: Yes, they are terminated automatically. But before that happens, lots of objects get destructed. Can your worker threads survive the destruction of, say, `frame[0].data` while they are still using it?

Comment: @Botje I totally agree with what you are saying, that why if you noticed in the complete code, I added an else clause to each reading task that prints to the terminal the message **Frame reading error**  if the `frame.data` is tested to empty. so why am I getting the error above instead of this message?

Comment: ... what if the shutdown starts in between the if test and the first access? This is a basic race condition and you should protect yourself against it. Either by delaying the shutdown unless both threads have finished, or killing them preemptively.

Comment: @Botje I think it a good idea. I'll try that and come back with an update.