# Discord.js, async and await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, discord.js

```js
const getNumberOfQuestions = async () => {
    await this.channel.send('How many questions should I ask? (1-10)')
        .then(async message => {
            await this.channel.awaitMessages(message => message.author.id === this.owner && !isNaN(parseInt(message.content)),  { max: 1, time: 15000 })
                .then(collected => {
                    this.channel.send(`You asked for ${collected.first().content} questions.`);
                    return parseInt(collected.first().content);
                })
                .catch(collected => {
                    this.channel.send('You did not tell me how many questions you wanted. Ending the quiz.');
                });
        });
};

const getDifficulty = async () => {
    await this.channel.send('What difficulty would you like: easy, medium, hard?')
        .then(message => {
            this.channel.awaitMessages(message => message.author.id === this.owner && ['easy', 'medium', 'hard'].includes(message.content.toLocaleLowerCase()),  { max: 1, time: 15000 })
                .then(collected => {
                    this.channel.send(`You asked for ${collected.first().content} difficulty.`);
                    return collected.first().content;
                })
                .catch(collected => {
                    this.channel.send('You did not tell which difficulty you wanted. Ending the quiz.');
                });
        });

};
getNumberOfQuestions();
getDifficulty();
```

With the above code, I do not want the execution to continue past this function when it is called. I clearly do not understand promises and await can some one help me?

`.send` and `.awaitMessages` both return a promise

Comment: You can't have control on the execution flow. With `async-await` the only thing you can be sure about is that the code **after** an `await` won't be executed till the result of the awaited expression is not returned

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I do not want the execution to continue past this function when it is called"?

Comment: Ivan, This function asks the user to select a number of questions. I then have more functions that ask other questions to the user that require input. Currently, all the question fire at the same time. I want to somehow wait until the first one is done, then ask the next one etc.

Comment: What you may need in that case is known as a lock, which would prevent multiple flows from entering the same critical section at the same time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34524/what-is-a-mutex

Comment: We don't see the code that asks the other questions which you'd like to make serial instead of parallel. Please make a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Ivan, I have updated the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me refactor your two procedures that have a mix of `promise`s and `async`/`await` so that they have just equivalent `async`/`await`.

```js
const getNumberOfQuestions = async () => {
    const message = await this.channel.send('How many questions should I ask? (1-10)');
    try {
        const collected = await this.channel.awaitMessages(message => message.author.id === this.owner && !isNaN(parseInt(message.content)),  { max: 1, time: 15000 });
        this.channel.send(`You asked for ${collected.first().content} questions.`);
        return parseInt(collected.first().content);
    } catch(collected) {
        this.channel.send('You did not tell me how many questions you wanted. Ending the quiz.');
    }
};

const getDifficulty = async () => {
    const message = await this.channel.send('What difficulty would you like: easy, medium, hard?');
    try {
        const collected = await this.channel.awaitMessages(message => message.author.id === this.owner && ['easy', 'medium', 'hard'].includes(message.content.toLocaleLowerCase()),  { max: 1, time: 15000 });
        this.channel.send(`You asked for ${collected.first().content} difficulty.`);
        return collected.first().content;
    } catch(collected) {
        this.channel.send('You did not tell which difficulty you wanted. Ending the quiz.');
    }
};
```

As you can see, `await`ing on a promise is like treating what's after it as inside a `then`, where the resolved value is what's returned by the `await`ed expression. The rejection (`.catch()`) of the promise is translated to an exception which can be `try{...}catch{...}`ed.

Knowing this, what you're doing by calling

```js
getNumberOfQuestions();
getDifficulty();
```

is calling both functions asynchronously - without waiting for the promises returned to settle. What you may want to do instead is to `await` the first's end before invoking the second. Like so:

```js
await getNumberOfQuestions();
await getDifficulty();
```

However, the `await` keyword makes sense only in an `async function`, so you can do it like so:

```js
(async()=>{
    await getNumberOfQuestions();
    await getDifficulty();
})();
```

More about async functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do this. I understand much better promises, async and await now!